# How can iI get row data table by click angular

Tags: angular

I'm using angular and lumen  to create a report. I have a list of data in a table created with mtx-grid. I want to show the row values in a dialog when i click in this row. This is my code.
I'm using angular and lumen  to create a report. I have a list of data in a table created with mtx-grid. I want to show the row values in a dialog when i click in this row. This is my code.

```
  <div class="contentTable">
<mtx-grid [data]="list"
[rowHover]="true" 
[rowStriped]="true"
[columns]="columns" 
[length]="total" 
[loading]="isLoading" 
(page)="getNextPage($event)"
[pageIndex]="query.page" 
[pageSizeOptions]="[20]" 
pageSize="20"
(click)="verNotificacion()">
</mtx-grid>
```

this is the ts file

```
 export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

columns: MtxGridColumn[] = [];
datos = [];
selectedRow;

list = [];
total = 0;
isLoading = true;
page = 0;
editId = 0;
query = {
    order: "desc",
    page: 0,
};
dialogRef;

constructor(
    public _listado: NotificacionesService,
    public dialog: MatDialog,

) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.columns = [
        {
            header: "date",
            field: "date",
            width: "120px",
        },
      
        {
            header: "Text",
            field: "text",
        },

     
    ];
    
    this.getData();
};

verNotificacion():void{

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NotificacionesDialogComponent, {
     
      });             


}

getNextPage(e: PageEvent) {
    this.page = e.pageIndex + 1;
    this.query.page = e.pageIndex;
    this.getData();
}

getData() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this._listado.getData(this.page).subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
            console.log(res);
            this.total = res.total;
            this.list = res.data.data;
            this.isLoading = false;
        },
        (error) => {
            this.isLoading = false;
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So can easily achieve it by passing desired values into the method

`(rowClick)="verNotificacion($event, column, total)">`

And don't forget to  accept those parameters in the method

```js
verNotificacion(rowClick, column, total): void {
  console.log(rowClick)
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NotificacionesDialogComponent, {
    data: {
      column,
      total
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Sorry for asking i am new in Angular but  would  I not need a loop in the html file to show me the specific row values when I click? I assume that the first parameter is columns from mtxgrid am I right? And where the variable total is come from? because in console.log column it's showing me the headers and total undefined

Comment: If `mtx-grid` generates rows by itself than you don't have to loop anything.
You better check documentation what API `mtx-grid` provides.
I guess they have `@Output` events so you can gain those events by passing 
`$event` into your method 

`(rowClick)="verNotificacion($event)">`

Comment: (rowClick) didn't work for me I resolved the issue with (cellSelectionChange)="verNotificacion($event)". Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Use `mtx-grid` property `rowClick` event emitter to get the Data.it will emit the object which contains `{ rowData, index }`

**`app.component.html`**

```
<div class="contentTable">
     <mtx-grid [data]="list"
          [rowHover]="true" 
          [rowStriped]="true"
          [columns]="columns" 
          [length]="total" 
          [loading]="isLoading" 
          (page)="getNextPage($event)"
          [pageIndex]="query.page" 
          [pageSizeOptions]="[20]" 
          pageSize="20"
          (rowClick)="verNotificacion($event)">
     </mtx-grid>  
</div>
```

**`app.component.ts`**

```
verNotificacion(row:any) {
     console.log(row) //output will be {rowData: <data>, index : <index>}
     console.log(row.rowData)
     console.log(row.index)
}
```

**Hope this helps :)**